# How to send keyboard shortcut Ctrl SHIFT U (hotkey) with C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, keypress, hotkeys

I am working with Wave tool for the Accessibility testing. And I have set Ctrl + Shift + U in the wave tool as toggle option to Open/Close Wave extension.

I am navigating to Google site and then want to open the extension by pressing the Ctrl+ Shift + U. 
I have tried a number of different option, But none works for me. (Extension is not opening.)

Below is the code snippet:

```
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://extensions/shortcuts");

    // Navigating to the Google homepage.
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.pl");

    //Option 1 : 
   Actions(driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("U").KeyUp(Keys.Alt).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Perform();

    //Option 2:

    driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "u");

   //Option 3:
    new Actions(driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("U").Build().Perform();

   //Option 4:
    new Actions(driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("U").KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Build().Perform();
```

Web browser: Chrome.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me in C#

```
IWebElement myElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//myPath"));
myElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: This worked? It triggered the Extension popup to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to send the keystrokes through Selenium? Have you tried just sending the key combination with `SendKeys` from `System.Windows.Forms`?

It would be something like:

```
SendKeys.Send("^+{U}");
```

Comment: I want to send keystrokes with c# with selenium only.

Comment: Try what I posted using the method in `Selenium` I assume it extends the Windows `SendKeys` class anyway.

Comment: @Frank Your assumption is incorrect. The Selenium project does not use `System.Windows.Forms` at all, much less for SendKeys.

Comment: @JimEvans Does it use the same logic for the key combinations though?

Comment: @Frank It most assuredly does not use the same syntax for "special keys" like Control or Shift.